# Zero Array size for medical images

Tags: python, tensorflow, medical

I am examining Uncertainty Maps for medical images (brain MRIs in .tif form) and I receive the following error in my code. 
**ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity**

this is my code:

```
def preprocess(ims):
    # convert to float32
    ims = ims.astype(np.float32)

    # scale to 0-1 interval
    if ims.max() > 1.0:
        ims /= 255.

    print('min: {}, max: {}, shape: {}, type: {}'.format(ims.min(), ims.max(), ims.shape, ims.dtype))
    return ims

x_train = preprocess(x_train)
x_test = preprocess(x_test)

y_train = preprocess(y_train)
y_test = preprocess(y_test)
```

I receive an error in:

**x_test = preprocess(x_test)**

when i print(x_test.shape), i get (0) -- which is very different from my training images where 
print(x_train.shape) gives me (23, 256, 256, 3).

[I have attached the test image that gives me (0) for x_test.shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiuTI.png)

I would deeply appreciate any help and guidance regarding this. Thank you!!

Comment: Please make sure the path to loading test image is correct.

Comment: You're calling max() on an empty array. Please include the code where you define x_test, as that is where the error truly lies.